# Matlab fft function swapping indices

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, fft

I've written a simple and very small Matlab code that calculates the Discrete Fourier Transfrom of a given array (or vector).

I worked it out manually and got an answer and my Matlab code also giving the same answer. But `fft` is giving an answer different from this by swapping indices. Here are the mannual calculations that I've done:

[image: This is the first image]

This is the second image:

[image: This is the second image]

This is the third image:

[image: This is the third image]

From those calculations it is clear that my answer would be `{12, -3-3j, -2, -3+3j}`

Here is the Matlab code that I've used:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
inp=[1,2,3,4];
j=sqrt(-1);
op=zeros(1,length(inp));
for k=1:length(inp)
    sigma=0;
    for n=1:length(inp)
        sigma=sigma+inp(n)*exp((j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1))/length(inp));
    end
    op(k)=sigma;
end
% Checking with fft
fft(inp)
```

Now I'm getting output as this:

[image: Matlab Output]

It is very much unexpected that I'm getting values swapped. It is swapping the indices 2 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong sign for your weights (which means you're probably doing an inverse FFT instead of a forward FFT - remember that for the forward transform [the weights are `exp(-j * theta)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition)).

Change:

```
    sigma=sigma+inp(n)*exp((j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1))/length(inp));
```

to:

```
    sigma=sigma+inp(n)*exp(-(j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1))/length(inp));
```